# IPython suddenly broken in conda environment: cannot import uniq_stable

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, anaconda, conda

I'm doing work in a conda environment. Today when I entered the environment, IPython failed to run, with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/d04/jayat/miniconda3/envs/umiopy/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    import IPython
  File "/home/d04/jayat/miniconda3/envs/umiopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/d04/jayat/miniconda3/envs/umiopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/home/d04/jayat/miniconda3/envs/umiopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 28, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/home/d04/jayat/miniconda3/envs/umiopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 127, in <module>
    from IPython.utils.data import uniq_stable
ImportError: cannot import name uniq_stable
```

IPython is up to date:

```
ipython                   5.3.0                    py27_0
```

It seems to be searching in the right place:

```
$ which ipython
~/miniconda3/envs/umiopy/bin/ipython
```

I'm using conda 4.3.14.

I've not changed anything in the environment but it's possible something has been updated by the system administrators (though it's hard to understand how that could affect my environment). What could be causing this problem? For similar errors on StackOverflow it seems like I'll need to update some module through conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever experiences this issue, after some period of time, reinstalling iPython resulted in it working. I have no idea what broke it in the first place, and why reinstalling didn't help previously. Some sort of conda-related problem I suppose.

It's this simple:

```
conda remove ipython
conda install ipython
```